# Facebook の一般ユーザーのウォールに自動投稿したい

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

複数人で投稿しているブログサイトがあります。
管理人が記事を承認後、投稿者のウォールへ記事を投稿したいと思っています。既存のCMSを用いておりますが、ウォールへの投稿についてはPHPにてバッチ処理の予定です。

Facebookアプリの管理者およびテストユーザーにて、App access tokenを利用して、アプリ承認後に投稿が可能でした。
※一般ユーザーの場合だと、挙動が異なるのでしょうか？
またユーザアクセストークンは必要でしょうか？

ちなみに現在、ユーザーIDを指定して投稿しています。

```
$me = (new FacebookRequest(
 $session, 'POST', '/ユーザーID/feed',$params   
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

ウォールへの投稿には、「publish_actions」が必要とのこと。
申請が必要だと聞きましたが、バッチ処理の場合でも審査時にアプリにアクセスできるような状態が必要なのでしょうか？？？
もしくはバッチ処理の場合は違う手順があるのでしょうか？
お忙しいところ大変恐縮ですが、ご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: 今回答できない状態になっていますがこれわかります。
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/?locale=ja_JP
に「新しいFacebookログインの一環として、public_profile、email、user_friends以外の権限を要求するアプリは、Facebookによるレビューを受ける必要があります。」とありまして、レビューを通らないとpublish_actionsは使えません。
というのはドキュメントを読んで理解されているかと推測しますが、ややこしいのは、レビューが必要な権限でも、管理者とテストユーザーはレビューされてなくてもこの権限を使う（テストする）ことが出来てしまうのです。
なので、レビューされてないけど使えるじゃんって思って開発すると一般ユーザーで使えなくて「あれ？」となってしまうのです。
ちなみに、レビューはまず通らないそうです。

Answer (score 1):

developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/?locale=ja_JP に「新しいFacebookログインの一環として、public_profile、email、user_friends以外の権限を要求するアプリは、Facebook‌​によるレビューを受ける必要があります。」とありまして、レビューを通らないとpublish_actionsは使えません。
 というのはドキュメントを読んで理解されているかと推測しますが、ややこしいのは、レビューが必要な権限でも、管理者とテストユーザーはレビューされてなくてもこの権限を‌​使う（テストする）ことが出来てしまうのです。 なので、レビューされてないけど使えるじゃんって思って開発すると一般ユーザーで使えなくて「あれ？」となってしまうのです。 
ちなみに、レビューはまず通らないそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！レビューはなかなか通らないとなると、現状ではアプリのアクセストークンよりも期限付きのユーザーアクセストークンを使用したほうがよいのでしょうか。

Comment: レビューが通らないというのでFacebookのAPIを使うのを諦めているのですが、期限付きのユーザーアクセストークンってlong-lived tokensのことですか？でしたら私はそれ理解してないのでよくわからないです。

Comment: アプリアクセストークンにしてもユーザーアクセストークンにしても、投稿には「publish_actions」の承認が必要ですよね。的外れなコメント、すみませんでした。ちなみに、ページへの投稿にはアプリアクセストークンは使用できないのでしょうか？テストでは、ページアクセストークンでしか投稿が成功しなかったのですが。